# I am having a problem loading library soiltexture in R

Tags: r, tcl

I am having a problem loading the `soiltexture` package in `R` version `4.1.1` on MacOS 11.3.1

I have tried 2 ways on installing:

1. `install.packages(soiltexture)`

with no error with installing

2.

```
install.packages(
pkgs = "soiltexture",
repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org"
)
```

with error of package `soiltexture` is not available for this version of R

When I just install with the first option then
library(soiltexture) I get this error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘soiltexture’: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details: call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so': dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so Reason: image not found
```

I see that '`tcltk`' is a base package so I not really sure where to go from here.

Have also tried

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("julienmoeys/soiltexture/pkg/soiltexture")
```

with this information and error:

```
Downloading GitHub repo julienmoeys/soiltexture@HEAD
✓  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/bq/x1vhzkf57p3fd9npyyb9wvlm0000gn/T/Rtmp1BYNgF/remotes14af6685ccbb4/julienmoeys-soiltexture-7586a8b/pkg/soiltexture/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘soiltexture’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  installing the package to process help pages
         -----------------------------------
─  installing *source* package ‘soiltexture’ ...
   ** using staged installation
   ** R
   ** inst
   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
   xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
   Warning in system2("/usr/bin/otool", c("-L", shQuote(DSO)), stdout = TRUE) :
     running command ''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/tcltk/libs//tcltk.so'' had status 1
   Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
     call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
     error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
     Reason: image not found
   Execution halted
   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘soiltexture’
─  removing ‘/private/var/folders/bq/x1vhzkf57p3fd9npyyb9wvlm0000gn/T/RtmpdN89vG/Rinst1523015dba5c8/soiltexture’
         -----------------------------------
   ERROR: package installation failed
```

```
Error: Failed to install 'soiltexture' from GitHub: System command 'R' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr: E> * checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/bq/x1vhzkf57p3fd9npyyb9wvlm0000gn/T/Rtmp1BYNgF/remotes14af6685ccbb4/julienmoeys-soiltexture-7586a8b/pkg/soiltexture/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK E> * preparing ‘soiltexture’: E> * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK E> * installing the package to process help pages E> ----------------------------------- E> * installing *source* package ‘soiltexture’ ... E> ** using staged installation E> ** R E> ** inst E> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading E> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun E> Warning in system2("/usr/bin/otool", c("-L", shQuote(DSO)), stdout = TRUE) : E> running command ''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/tcltk/libs//tcltk.so'' had status
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcl/tk was a popular UI scripting language before python became popular.

Looking at your error, I assume you are on Windows. The package is missing the tcl shared libraries. See here - https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/How+to+compile+Tcl+and+related+C+extensions+on+Windows

**Step 1** - is tcl/tk working without R: Find wish.exe of tcltk and start it. Does it work ?

**Step 2** - Check the value of the environment variable MY_TCLTK
Does it point to the bin folder of Tcl/Tk? If not: Fix it.

If not defined: Set value to bin folder.

See here - https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Package-TclTk-does-not-work_002e

Comment: Ah yes I sorry I just edited with information that I am running Mac OS. Would these steps still apply?

Comment: Try check Step 2. Its not finding the shared lib. Definitely an issue with the env variables.

Comment: I am a bit lost on how to actually check the value of MY_TCLTK and how to set a value to a bin folder after reading the provided link.

Comment: How did you install R ?

Comment: Open terminal - type `env | grep TCL`

Comment: bash: TCL: command not found 
is what I get

Comment: What happens when you type `env`

Comment: I have a feeling that R is not installed properly. Re-install R and the issue should go away.